# How to convert string date into NSDate with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following date as NSString:

```
Thu May 29 14:22:40 UTC 2014
```

I've tried to convert it to NSDate with the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.dateFormat =                  @"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
NSDate *utc = [fmt dateFromString:@"Thu May 29 14:22:40 UTC 2014"];
NSLog(@"UTC Date:%@:", utc);
```

The result is **nil**
I've tried several *dateFormat* regex expressions but with no luck.

What am I missing here?

Comment: date formats changes in different OS versions, where are you running on?

Comment: Wasn't May 5, 2014 a Monday?

Comment: The date formatter frequently does not like to parse day-of-week.  Better to substring that out.  (Especially since May 5 was a Monday, and May 29 was a Tuesday.)

Comment: Excelent catch @Anna.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [NSDataDetector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class a subclasss of NSRegularExpression, its takes a string that of a unknown date and converts it to NSDate object if it finds a match.

```
   NSError *error;
    NSDataDetector *data = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
    NSString *dateRaw = @"Thu May 29 14:22:40 UTC 2014"; // your date

    NSDate *date = [data firstMatchInString:dateRaw
                                    options:NSMatchingReportCompletion
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, dateRaw.length)].date;

    NSLog(@"Date: %@",  date);
```

Comment: Nice! Though it can't parse date string like `2012-04-11T18:34:19+07:00`. In that case it's still better to use `NSDateFormatter`.