# How do I convert the string(2014-07-17T09:00:00-04:00) to the format below? yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have a string to convert to date.

The response string is

```
2014-07-17T09:00:00-04:00
```

where:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-(04:00 is the offset)
```

How do I convert the `"2014-07-17T09:00:00-04:00"` as string to the format below?

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739825/how-to-convert-string-date-into-nsdate-with-nsdateformatter/24740807#24740807

Comment: Srinivasan, it is not exactly the same problem. But I tested holex answer, which works exactly as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if that is an *Objective-C* question, I would do this:

```
NSString *_stringDate = @"2014-07-17T09:00:00-04:00";
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *_date = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:_stringDate];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *_stringWithRequestedDateFormat = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:_date];
NSLog(@"%@", _stringWithRequestedDateFormat);
```

---

if that is a *Swift* question, I would do that:

```
let stringDate: String = "2014-07-17T09:00:00-04:00"
var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(stringDate)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let stringWithRequestedDateFormat: String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
println(stringWithRequestedDateFormat)
```

---

the console shows in both cases:

```
2014-07-17 14:00:00
```

Comment: Having being in iOS only few months,trying to get things right. That perfectly works for me. You are the real MVP.